# SAS: proc import where get_names is at variable row

Tags: excel, import, sas

I have an excel spreadsheet where the names of columns for my first 5 columns are on the 2nd row, and the name for columns on all the other columns are on the 3rd row.
Data starts for every column at row 4.

How can I load this data efficiently in SAS with the appropriate names?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way would be to make the change in excel.

A slower way would be:

1) use two different import procedures: one for first 5 columns and another for the rest of the columns. You can do this using the RANGE= option in proc import. now you'll have two data sets in work library.

2) Use a data steps to remove empty rows that are between col headers and first row of data.

3) Then use data step to create a row number variable for each data set (using the statement *N*= ) and do a one-to-one merge to combine the two.

If anyone knows a faster way, let me know. This is the first that came to mind.

Comment: a change in excel is impossible because the same format is generated across 90 tabs in 12 sheets. It's a direct import from a plugin that generates this kind of output.... I'll try your solution thanks

Comment: I see. Yeah I figured it was a huge data set. Hope you figured it out!